# (Custom) domain restrictions for NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm new to mathematica, so please be forbearing with me :D

I would like to use NMaximize together with domain restriction (where the domain is a custom domain).

I've got an example:

```
dom = {1, 2, 3, 4};
NMaximize[{UP[fl, a, p], UA[fl, a, p] >= resutil, 
  D[UAS[fl, a, p], X[a]] == D[DA[a], a], MemberQ[dom, a] == True}, {a,
   p}]
```

I would like to maximize UP(.), subject to the given constraints (including that the result for a is a member of dom).

The maximization works fine if I set the constraint to `a \[Element] Integers`:

```
NMaximize[{UP[fl, a, p], UA[fl, a, p] >= resutil, 
  D[UAS[fl, a, p], X[a]] == D[DA[a], a], a \[Element] Integers}, {a, 
  p}]
```

Is there a way to include such a constraint into NMaximize?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Can't you combine `Integers` with adding `UP>0&&UP<5` in the curly brackets?

Comment: Thank you Feyre, maybe the example above isn't the best. Let's say the solution where a is restricted to Integers is a=4 and p=0.25; in a second step I would like to limit the possible values for a to dom={1,2,5,7,8} and find the optimal values for a and p where a \element dom

Comment: If `dom` is a small list in fact, what's the trouble with brute-force enumeration?

Comment: Thank you J.M :) .. `dom` is not necessarily a small list. Anyhow, even if `dom` were a small list, `p` can take any value (i.e., there are a lot possible combinations of `a` and `p`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your question your are trying to use `NMaximize` where you want to constrain a parameter to belong to a custom domain.

One way to do it is to use `Or` on the individual elements of the domain list.

dom = {1, 2, 3, 4};

```
Or @@ Map[a == # &, dom]

(* a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3 || a == 4 *)
```

Use this in `NMaximize` as a constraint.

```
NMaximize[{a^2, Or @@ Map[a == # &, dom]}, a]

(* {16., {a -> 4.}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) That's exactly what I was trying to do :)